# Python request freezing after status code 200

Tags: python, json, get, python-requests

I'm attempting to perform a get request, however my instance of idle is consistently freezing/crashing when attempting to do so.

```
import requests

url = 'https://zkillboard.com/api/history/20161217/'
req = requests.get(url)
print(req.status_code)
print(req.text)
```

Ouput:

```
>>> 
============= RESTART: D:\Google Drive\eveSoloPredictor\test.py =============
200
```

*then crashes

I am able to request this url and receive a JSON response both in my browser and using postman with no issues. Also, I am able to request other URL's in this script absolutely fine.

Comment: try doing this in the command prompt, just to test and see what you get

Comment: @SuperStew Very strange, I am able to get it to work via command line (windows - both by running the script and by using the python shell). Thought it might be a permissions issue for IDLE but I don't think this is the case. Could the size of the JSON data be crashing the IDLE gui?  Edit: I think it's something to do with print, I'm able to iterate through the data once stored in a variable - original issue isn't a huge problem now, but I would still be curious as to why it crashes.